# Why does Japan allow unlimited terms for their Prime Ministers?

Tags: japan

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_political_term_limits

Why does Japan allow unlimited terms for their Prime Ministers? I saw that Japan allows unlimited 4-years terms for their Prime Minister meaning that the Prime Minister can hold power for more than 100 years theoretically if one lives long enough. Isn't that a bad thing for a democracy? If so, why did Japan decide to allow for unlimited terms?

Comment: This is a common feature of countries with parliamentary systems. See [the list on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_political_term_limits) for the many countries without term limits for the head of government.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know any term limits applying to prime ministers and, perusing the Wikipedia list, I do not see any. That's the default setup for a parliamentary democracy where the head of government must command the confidence of parliament (or one of its chambers). The Japanese political system is peculiar in many way but there is absolutely nothing special about the lack of term limits.

Answer (score 3):

Prime Ministers in Japan do not tend to serve a very long amount of time.  Since the end of WWII, the longest-serving Prime Minister was Shinzo Abe, who served for just under eight years from 2012-2020 (plus a single year in 2006-2007).  Japanese Prime Ministers have tended to resign rather swiftly on a scandal, before having to face a general election.  Thus, the need for term limits has never really come up in Japan.

Answer (score 1):

Political term limits are a fairly popular addition to political systems, but also seem fairly recent.  The US only introduced it after Roosevelt won 4 terms.

They don't always cover all the bases.  Putin used the old shell game with his PM to reset his count to zero.  Mexico had a problem with the PRI remaining in power for decades, not necessarily just with presidential alternance.  Likewise, Japan has had problems with political over-continuity and stagnation, but at the [party level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politics_of_Japan), not PM level.

> Several political parties exist in Japan. However, the politics of Japan have primarily been dominated by the LDP since 1955, with the DPJ playing an important role as opposition several times. The LDP was the ruling party for decades since 1955, despite the existence of multiple parties. Most of the prime ministers were elected from inner factions of the LDP.

Finally they actively limit the voters' choices, assuming voters are not qualified to decide whether or not electing a leader yet again is a good thing.  Say a Republican, other than Trump, wins in 2024, and 2028.  In 2032, Trump runs a strong primary campaign, but the popular incumbent Rep POTUS can't be picked to head him off?